# Gradle won't pick up Android build tools unless opened in Android Studio

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm preparing an Android build pipeline in Jenkins, on a Windows build server. Jenkins uses a number of workspaces and will often re-use them. I've noticed that when Jenkins re-uses a workspace, there are no problems and a build goes perfectly. But when it first checks out a new workspace, the gradle wrapper complains that it cannot install Android build-tools. The build tools (the exact version) are already installed.

I can open another older workspace and run the gradle build in there and it works perfectly and then, with the same login and in the exact same `cmd` session, go to the new workspace and run the same command and it complains that it cannot install Android build-tools.

A note about the Android configuration: I'm storing the Android SDK in `C:\android-sdk\` and have given every user access to that directory. ANDROID_HOME and ANDROID_SDK are set as system-wide variables. This is the most convenient solution- this way every user that logs in, domain account or otherwise, is (in theory) able to immediately build the solution without having to set up their own SDK, and we don't end up with a lot of duplicated SDK data.

I can fix the issue manually by opening the workspace folder in Android Studio. Just doing this alone seems to fix the issue. My hypothesis is that somewhere there's a cached value in the project metadata telling gradle where to find the Android build-tools, and when I open Android Studio it updates this value.

Obviously the work-around isn't adequate because the build needs to work consistently every time without human intervention. Is there some command I can use to refresh this cache? Or perhaps some configuration files that are checked into git that shouldn't be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Gradle looks in two places, in order of priority, for your SDK: Firstly, it checks whether a local.properties file specifies the SDK. Then, it tries the ANDROID_HOME (not ANDROID_SDK) system variable. Opening a folder in Android Studio generates the local.properties file, which is why that work-around worked.

I had no local.properties file, but my ANDROID_HOME was set to the Android Studio install folder rather than the Android SDK. When I moved it to the SDK and re-started the Jenkins agent service it worked.